# JSON Property names with dots in Javascript using Jackson-like library

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, jackson

I need to create a Json with field names with dots '.' in javascript application (typescript)

Json expected output:

```
{
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "topics": "eraseme_topic_schema_test_v05"
 }
```

I have tried ts-jackson and jackson-js, Code example using ts-jackson

MyDomain.ts

```
@Serializable()
import { JsonProperty,Serializable } from 'ts-jackson';
export class MyDomain{
        @JsonProperty({path: 'tasks.max', elementType: String})
        tasks_max: string;
        @JsonProperty({path: 'key.converter'})
        key_converter: string;
        @JsonProperty({path: 'topics'})
        topics: string;
}
```

But the properties with dots are created as subclasses in Json output instead a property field with dot.

```
{
  tasks: { max: '1' },
  key: { converter: { schema: [Object] } },
  topics: 'eraseme_topic_schema_test_v05'
}
```

How can I set dots in Json fields name in Javascript using a Jackson-like library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This comment by joniba](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3529#issuecomment-448586433) on the lodash github repo shows how to access properties containing dots using lodash:

```js
// lodash set
const o = {}
_.set(o, 'a["b.c"]', 1)
// returns { a: { 'b.c': 1 } }
```

This works with lodash get:

```js
// lodash get
const obj = {'a.b': 'value'};
_.get(obj, '["a.b"]'); // 'value'
```

---

So it should be possible to write the ts-jackson `path` properties like this:

```
export class MyDomain{
    @JsonProperty({path: '["tasks.max"]', elementType: String})
    tasks_max: string;
    @JsonProperty({path: '["key.converter"]'})
    key_converter: string;
    @JsonProperty({path: 'topics'})
    topics: string;
}
```